# Analyzing underlying features instead of time series

Tags: time-series, logistic, modeling

I'm trying to make a model for predicting whether a hotel room will be booked at a given time and at a given price.

I have collected historical booking data and have data on room types. I'm planning to use logistic regression to estimate the likelihood of room getting booked at a future date.

I see a lot of overfitting challenges in using the historical time series data to predict future bookings. As an example specific event have huge impact on bookings and they typically do not repeat each year. I'm therefore considering just looking at hotel, room type, price, weather, weekday and a special demand feature.

I believe weather, weekday and the special demand feature [a proxy for events, holidays etc] are the underlying features explaining the differences in bookings throughout the season.

I realize that the generating the demand feature introduces a new challenges but I have already worked quite a bit on so called pick-up models and therefore already have a good idea of demand on historical and future dates.

Does that makes sense? It would hopefully make the logistic model less complicated and allow me to get rid of the time dimension.

Comment: Can you give some more details on your data?  Do you have , for each day, $N$, the total number of available rooms, and $X$, the number of booked rooms?  Maybe the same, for each of a series of different room types?  If the data is of this form, I would start with a logistic regression, and then look if there is autocorrelation in the residuals ...